# Howto add diashapes to dia

Tags: graphics

I downloaded the diashapes.deb package from http://dia-installer.de/download/linux.html .
I installed the deb-file, but the objects don't appear in Dia. Where are they????

thank you in advance

chris

Comment: Is there a reason you installed the deb directly?  It's available via apt-get(tested on 12.04).

Comment: I downloaded additional objects, not the dia-program.

Comment: `apt-cache search dia-shapes` results in `dia-shapes - Diagram editor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded Dia from the Software Centre, all the shapes and objects are there.  Try downloading it from USC unless you have a compelling reason not to.

- Regarding the diashapes.deb package but I would imagine objects would
  be stored where the main objects and shapes are  usr/share/dia. Give
  that a try.
- If that doesn't work Dia creates a hidden folder on your
  Home folder.  There is an "Objects" subfolder.  To view this navigate
  to your home folder and select [Ctrl]H to reveal hidden folders and
  files.
- To add them Select File >> Sheets and Objects then New.
- Navigate to your new objects and select them for using.

Alternatively press F9

Comment: I didn't download the dia-program. I downloaded additional shapes / templates. I don't know where they were installed.

Comment: thank you. it also adds a link ot the gnome applications menu.